# Trying to recall an integration trick

Tags: integration, contest-math

In my notes, I have the following problem.

> Find the volume of
>
> (a) $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, $x^2+z^2\le 1$ in $\mathbb R^3$
>
> (b) $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, $x^2+z^2\le 1$, $y^2+z^2\le 1$ in $\mathbb R^3$
>
> (c) $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 \le 1$ in $\mathbb R^4$

Observe that these form interesting geometric shapes. The first is the intersection of two orthogonal cylinders, the second in the intersection of three orthogonal cylinders, and the third is the $4$-ball.

One can of course bash these with messy calculus. However, I copied this problem down when it was presented to me because each part had a clever solution that was not very computational. In particular, I vaguely remember doing the last one by taking the four iterated integrals in pairs. I do not remember how this helps. I think it was something to do with recognizing each as the area of a circle.

**Question:** How does one cleverly and with minimal computation find the above volumes?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a *trick*, but the first two have lots of symmetry which makes them pretty easy. These are called [Steinmetz solids](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html).

Comment: @oldrinb I would be interested to see your answer, then.

Comment: @julien Thank you. It was supposed to be the unit ball. I have corrected it.

Comment: Talking about symmetries, it is hard to beat the ball. You can find all you need [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball). Whether you decide to reduce this to the $2$ ball or the $3$ ball. But maybe that's not what you call clever and minimal. Technique 1: Fubini separating $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$. Technique 2: $(x,y,z)$ and $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> doing the last one by taking the four iterated integrals in pairs. I do not remember how this helps. I think it was something to do with recognizing each as the area of a circle

If the coordinates are divided into pairs, like $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$, the slices of the volume in each "pair space" are discs.  The volume of the subset where $x^2 + y^2 \in [r, r+dr]$ is $(2\pi r \hskip2pt dr)\times \pi (1-r^2)$ so that $V = \pi^2 \int_0^1 2r(1-r^2) dr = \pi^2(\frac{1}{2})$.

Given how perfectly adapted the integral is for the use of $r^2$ (or $1-r^2$) as the integration variable, there may be a better way to say this that maps directly to the area of a triangle.

Comment: In $2n$ dimensions the volume is $\pi^n / n!$ so it is likely that using the squares of the radii you can get a similarly nice integral that computes the volume of the $n$ dimensional standard simplex.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean things like for (e.g.) $x^{2}+y^{2}<1$, taking:$$\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}} dx=2\cdot \sqrt{1-y^{2}}$$
and then: $$\int_{-1}^{1} 2\cdot \sqrt{1-y^{2}}dy$$

which is [click here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral&a=%2aC.integral-_%2aCalculator.dflt-&f2=sqrt%281-x%2ax%29&x=8&y=11&f=Integral.integrand_sqrt%281-x%2ax%29&a=%2aFVarOpt.1-_%2a%2a-.%2a%2a%2aIntegral.rangestart-.%2aIntegral.rangeend--.%2a%2aIntegral.variable---.%2a--)?